EXTRA_STREAM option doesn't seem to be working
I'm using GDAL to generate geoPDF's and I have the following code to generate the geopdf itself:
    # Add EXTRA_STREAM to the creation options
    options = [
        "COMPOSITION_FILE=" + xml_composition_file_path,
        "EXTRA_STREAM=BT 0 0 0 rg /F1 12 Tf 550 500 Td (Custom Text) Tj ET",  # Add the text as an extra stream
    ]

    # Create the GeoPDF
    out_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName("PDF").Create(
        geopdf_file_path,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        gdal.GDT_Unknown,
        options=options,
    )

The geopdf is generated successfully but I want to add text to it and I'm EXTRA_STREAM for that purpose but the text I put in that option doesn't seem to be appearing. I'm using GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27

Have a look at this GDAL autotest https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/pdf.py#L1415 and compare your code with it.

Hi @user30184, yes I did!
I even try to use the same EXTRA_STREAM string as the example but it still didn't work.
Do you see any difference from that example that might do the difference in my case?
Thank you!
